# Create barplot R for coverage

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a barplot and my data is in a csv file in the following format

```
0,22
40,50
80,62
120,70
160,62
200,49
240,52
280,64
320,57
360,50
400,47
440,52
480,73
520,70
560,68
600,71
640,69
680,61
720,59
760,59
800,62
840,62
880,62
920,72
960,81
1000,89
1040,86
1080,76
1120,80
1160,95
```

The element before the comma should be the position in the x axis and the element after the comma the height= of the bar at that position. I can do this in Excel but the data is large.
The graph I want would look like this.

[image]

I have tried the following but I think it sums the data in each row.

```
data <- as.matrix(read.csv(file="data.csv",sep=",",header=FALSE))
barplot(data)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
barplot(x$V2, names.arg = seq_len(nrow(x)), cex.names = .6)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

two things:  first, if you supply the whole matrix to the height parameter of barplot, it will sum them.  instead, give it only your data.

```
dput(dat)
structure(c(0L, 40L, 80L, 120L, 160L, 200L, 240L, 280L, 320L, 
360L, 400L, 440L, 480L, 520L, 560L, 600L, 640L, 680L, 720L, 760L, 
800L, 840L, 880L, 920L, 960L, 1000L, 1040L, 1080L, 1120L, 1160L, 
22L, 50L, 62L, 70L, 62L, 49L, 52L, 64L, 57L, 50L, 47L, 52L, 73L, 
70L, 68L, 71L, 69L, 61L, 59L, 59L, 62L, 62L, 62L, 72L, 81L, 89L, 
86L, 76L, 80L, 95L), .Dim = c(30L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
    c("V1", "V2")))

barplot(height=dat[,2])
```

second, you need to supply the `names.arg` to barplot to get the labeling:

```
barplot(height=dat[,2], names.arg=dat[,1])
```

a side note: its best to avoid naming variables with built in R functions.  `?data` is probably the most commonly overwritten!  I use `dat` instead regularly.

Comment: alternatively you could try `plot(dat[,1],dat[,2],type="h",lwd=4)`

Comment: I showed only a subset of the data I have. My dataset is made up of 6M data points, so I probably wont be able to give it my data manually. Is there a way to extract the data?

Comment: the dat[,1] dat[,2] syntax that Ben and I are using is selecting columns from your matrix rather than individual data points.  However, 6 million bars won't look like much.  You might want to think about alternative ways of displaying the data.

Answer (score 1):

Using your method of getting the data into R:

```
myData <- read.csv(file = "data.csv", sep = ",", header = FALSE)
```

To make sure that the order of the bars follows the order of the values in the first column (although this is not strictly what you asked for in your question)

```
myData2 <- myData[order(myData[, 1]), ]

barplot(myData2[, 2], names.arg = myData2[, 1])
```

[image: A barplot]

For tweaking the graph, I recommend spending some time reading `?barplot` and `?par`